# pandas parse_dates does not seem to work

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have this sample of a data_frame:

```
name,time_0
name,22/04/2014 00:44
OTROGUAPOSUELTO,22/04/2014 13:20
```

I want to parse time_0, but doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data_string,header=0,parse_dates='time_0', dayfirst=True)
```

brings me back an 'object' dtype for time_0, instead of a date_time object.

Anyone?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: `parse_dates` accepts a boolean or a list, list of lists or a dict, by passing a string it is likely to convert `'time_0'` into an array of chars `'t''i''m''e''_''0'`, so you need to pass either the ordinal or column name enclosed in square brackets like @Amit has done in his answer, see the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(data_string, header=0, parse_dates=[1], dayfirst=True)

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]:
name              object
time_0    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: It can also be fixed by by adding [] around 'time_0' for the parse_dates option:  `parse_dates=['time_0']`.

Comment: thanks everyone, after thinking, I think the problem was in my data.